# puppeteer fails to write / read clipboard

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, clipboard

The following code throws an exception:
Uncaught Error Error: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Write permission denied.

Environment: Nodejs version: v16.13.1
puppeteer version: puppeteer@14.4.1

```
      'use strict';
      const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
      const URL = 'https://google.com';
      (async () => {
          const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
          const context = browser.defaultBrowserContext();
          context.overridePermissions(URL, ['clipboard-read', 'clipboard-write']);
          const page = await browser.newPage();
          await page.goto(URL, {
            waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
          });
      
          await page.evaluate(() => navigator.clipboard.writeText("Injected"));
      
          const value = await page.evaluate(() => navigator.clipboard.readText());
          console.log(value);
      })();
```

Comment: Works in headful mode but not in headless mode for me too, tried mocking the clipboard api as well.

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly? It's rather odd to need to use the clipboard in Puppeteer and I suspect there's a [more direct solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676) to whatever functionality you're trying to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. The response of "It just works in headful mode" is wrong.

You need to override browser permissions.

```js
const context = await browser.defaultBrowserContext();
await context.overridePermissions(spec.url, ['clipboard-read', 'clipboard-write']);
```